# Does hbase support double rows id filtering?

Tags: java, scala, hbase

Suppose I have designed hbase row id in following format (`-` is used as delimiters, `_` instead of spaces):

```
timestamp-event_type-user_id
```

So now I want to select event sequences for user. For example, I need to select event typs than go in following sequence: 4,8,1,10.
It is obvious that I should create [RowFilter](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/RowFilter.html) combined with [RegexStringComparator](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/RegexStringComparator.html).
But in that case I select a group of rows, so it needs to extract them and order by timestamp to determine event sequence.
Is there a an approach in hbase to apply row filter twice? E.g. first to select row and second to perform selection in selected group?

**Note**

It may be seems not correct use of hbase, but the main idea is row key are stored in Hbase cache, so double filtering on row keys should be extremely fast. Does hbase provides something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [FilterList](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/FilterList.html).

It could take multiple filters and join them by conditions. eg: `MUST_PASS_ALL` (AND) or `MUST_PASS_ONE` (OR).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this code for reference:**

```
FilterList filterList = new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL);

filterList.addFilter(new RowFilter(...));

filterList.addFilter(new RowFilter(...));

Scan s = new Scan();
s.setFilter(filterList);
```

You can find more on http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/FilterList.html